# Corporate Proxy Azure Devops with Git

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've created a Project and Repo inside of Azure Dev-Ops. 
We are sitting behind a corporate proxy and would like to clone from this project.

I have set the environment variables http_proxy,https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY,HTTPS_PROXY, git config --global https.proxy, git config --global http.proxy to the matching http or https version below
[http://domain\username:password@ProxAddr:Proxy](http://domain%5Cusername:password@ProxAddr:Proxy)
or
[https://domain\username:password@ProxAddr:Proxy](https://domain%5Cusername:password@ProxAddr:Proxy)

When I run git clone https://username:pwd@dev.azure.com/username/ProjectName/_git/RepoName, I receive the error below.

```
Cloning into 'ProjectName'...
* Couldn't find host dev.azure.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying {proxyip} ...
* Connected to {proxyip} ({proxyip}) port {proxyport} (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to dev.azure.com:443
> CONNECT dev.azure.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.azure.com:443
User-Agent: git/2.7.4
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="{CORPRELM}"
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 849
<
* Ignore 849 bytes of response-body
* Connect me again please
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
* Closing connection 0
* Couldn't find host dev.azure.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname {proxyip} was found in DNS cache
*   Trying {proxyip}...
* Connected to {proxyip} ({proxyip}) port {proxyport}(#1)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to dev.azure.com:443
> CONNECT dev.azure.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.azure.com:443
User-Agent: git/2.7.4
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="{CORPREALM}"
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 849
<
* Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
* Closing connection 1
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:devopspwdF@dev.azure.com/username/DevOpsProject/_git/DevOpsRepo/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
```

The error appears to be this?

```
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
```

Do I need to explicitly state something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to a newer version of git resolves this.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your proxy may be misconfigured, and is offering authentication mechanisms it can't support (in this case, Negotiate).  You can work around this by setting the `http.proxyAuthMethod` option to something suitable.  Based on the output, you'll probably want to use `ntlm` or `basic`.

In addition, you can set this on a per-url or pattern basis by using something like `git config http.https://*.azure.com/.proxyAuthMethod ntlm` for all HTTPS URLs with hostnames matching `*.azure.com`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps get farther. I set the parameters and it did not have an affect although reading the documentation suggests it would. I ran curl directly (encapsulated by git) and in the handshake it sends the following lines which are omitted by git.
 'Proxy auth using Basic with user '{domain}}\{username}'' and 
'Server auth using Basic with user '{username}''  
These are omitted when running git.

Comment: That's probably because the version of Git you're using is too old.  You'd require Git 2.8.0 for the option to exist in the configuration.  It looks like you're using 2.7.4.